# Ionicons version 5 with angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, nebular, ionicons

How to add ionicons version 5 to angular, with version 4.5 there was a scss available and I can use in that way but now in version 5 ionicons use svgs and don't know how to integrate it with angular.

Current approach
In angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss/ionicons.scss",
              "src/app/theme/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
```

Then in my app.component.ts (I'm using nebular UI)
https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/register-icon-pack#register-icon-pack

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private iconsLibrary: NbIconLibraries, public store$: Store<any>, ) {
    iconsLibrary.registerFontPack('ion', { iconClassPrefix: 'ion' });
    iconsLibrary.registerFontPack('nebular', { iconClassPrefix: 'nb' });
    iconsLibrary.setDefaultPack('nebular');
    // @ts-ignore
    if (window.Cypress) {
      // @ts-ignore
      window.__appStore__ = store$;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I see in issues that for ionic with angular them add

```
"assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ]
```

but I don't know how to continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily hack the icons.

I created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/marchrius/3a64d96aefe00c7931495a5d2a435273), you can download and it to your project.

Then import the `NbIonIcons` const in `AppComponent` and then add it using the Nebular method `registerSvgPack` from `NbIconLibraries` (example below)

```
...
import {NbIonIcons} from './icons';
....
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private iconsLibrary: NbIconLibraries, public store$: Store<any>, ) {
    iconsLibrary.registerFontPack('ion', { iconClassPrefix: 'ion' });
    iconsLibrary.registerFontPack('nebular', { iconClassPrefix: 'nb' });

    iconsLibrary.registerSvgPack('ionicons', NbIonIcons);

    iconsLibrary.setDefaultPack('nebular');
    // @ts-ignore
    if (window.Cypress) {
      // @ts-ignore
      window.__appStore__ = store$;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

At this point you can use you icons as usual.

```
<nb-icon icon="home-outline" pack="ionicons"></nb-icon>
```

Keep in mind that you have to update the list if icons are added / removed from package.

Comment: seems like this should work, didnt have time this week to test it. the only annoying thing is the manually part when ionic get update. I will approve it soon ty.

Comment: This is working. However, I am not able to style the icons via nb-icon. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can extend the nbIcon service/directive and use the useClass to provide the new directive. I done a similar devlop on the NbMenu adding the tooltips on it but using the original NbMenuService

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: npm install ionicons

Step 2: include ionicons in assets in angular.json

```
"assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons",
            "output": "./ionicons"
          },
          {
            "glob": "**/*.js",
            "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/",
            "output": "./"
          }
        ],
```

Step 3: Add script in Index.html

```
<body class="mat-typography">
<app-root></app-root>
  <script type="module" src="ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule="" src="ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
```

Step 4: Add schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ] in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

if you are using ion-icon in another module add schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ] so you won't get web component error.

Step 5: Use Regular like

```
<ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ionicons ver 5 doesn't looks like supporting font icon file like Ionic 4 ,https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/tree/4.x#using-the-font-icon anymore.

Comment: i've searched in forums for days, cleaning cache, installing npm, this solution worked like a charm